# aws cli automatically terminates my clusters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm running the following command using aws cli v2 on Windows 10

```
aws2 emr create-cluster --name "Spark cluster with step" \
--release-label emr-5.24.1 \
--applications Name=Spark \
--log-uri s3://boris-bucket/logs/ \
--ec2-attributes KeyName=boris-key \
--instance-type m5.xlarge \
--instance-count 1 \
--bootstrap-actions Path=s3://boris-bucket/bootstrap_file.sh \
--steps Type=Spark,Name="Spark job",ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,Args=[--deploy-mode,cluster,--master,yarn] \
--use-default-roles \
--no-auto-terminate
```

And the EC2 instance **still** terminates after launching and running for some time (about 5 minutes).

What am I missing? is there an option somewhere which supersedes my --no-auto-terminate?

EDIT: okay I figured it out, my `bootstrap-actions` were not valid. I found that out by looking at the log file for my node

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about emr, but when i checked the cli specification, it says `--no-auto-terminate` is a boolean. you should provide a value.

```
aws2 emr create-cluster --name "Spark cluster with step" \
...
--no-auto-terminate true
```

But the documentation also says, the auto termination is off by default. You should pass `--termination-protected` to the cli, then you can inspect the dashboard to see whats happening.

```
aws2 emr create-cluster --name "Spark cluster with step" \
...
--no-auto-terminate
--termination-protected
```

Because my guess is that the cluster is failing for some reason, even though you have set `ActionOnFaulure = Continue`, the cluster will terminate for failures when the `Termination Protection` is not enabled.

Reference:
https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/UsingEMR_TerminationProtection.html

Hope this helps. Good Luck.

Comment: I tired using both `--no-auto-terminate --termination-protected` as you suggested, it still terminates. Is there anywhere in the logs where it will say what the issue is?

Comment: can you goto dashboard and check the attributes you have set from the command line are present , https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/UsingEMR_TerminationProtection.html

Comment: Where is the dashboard to see those?

Comment: I mean the AWS console for emr. The link I gave you has some instructions

Comment: oh that, yeah I checked and the attributes were not there (for example termination protection was off). It seems if it fails on bootstrap it doesn't set the other attributes and my bootstrap script had an error which made it crash

Comment: Glad you found the way forward?